# Spherical building of an algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and $X$ its spherical building, that is, $X$ is the set of maximal proper parabolic subgroups of $G$ and the simplices of $X$ are the finite subsets of $X$ of the form $S=\{P_{1},\ldots,P_{r}\}$, where $P_{i}\in X$, such that $P_{1}\cap \ldots \cap P_{r}$ is a parabolic subgroup. My question is: what is the appartement of $X$?

Comment: I guess you mean "what ARE the appartments of X" ? I am not sure I know the abstract definition of what an appartment should be in an abstract building, but in this case, I think appartments are in bijection with maximal split tori, and the appartment associated to such a torus T consists of all parabolic subgroups that contain T.

Comment: Jef is right. There are nice books on buildings, Ronan's "Buildings" is my favorite. If you want to see a quick introduction, then you can read Brown's "What is a building?", Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 49 (2002), no. 10, 1244-1245, or, for more details, his "Five lectures on buildings." Group theory from a geometrical viewpoint (Trieste, 1990), 254–295, World Sci. Publishing, River Edge, NJ, 1991.